# Differences between OT and CRDT

Tags: algorithm, paxos, operational-transform, crdt, nosql

Can someone explain me simply the main differences between Operational Transform and CRDT?

As far as I understand, both are algorithms that permits data to converge without conflict on different nodes of a distributed system.

In which usecase would you use which algorithm?
As far as I understand, OT is mostly used for text and CRDT is more general and can handle more advanced structures right?

Is CRDT more powerful than OT?

---

I ask this question because I am trying to see how to implement a collaborative editor for HTML documents, and not sure in which direction to look first. I saw the ShareJS project, and their attempts to support rich text collaboration on the browser on `contenteditables` elements. Nowhere in ShareJS I see any attempt to use CRDT for that.

We also know that Google Docs is using OT and it's working pretty well for real-time edition of rich documents.
Is Google's choice of using OT because CRDT was not very known at that time? Or would it be a good choice today too?

I'm also interested to hear about other use cases too, like using these algorithms on databases. Riak seems to use CRDT. Can OT be used to sync nodes of a database too and be an alternative to Paxos/Zab/Raft?

Comment: You should read the TreeDoc paper which is designed for your purposes https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00445975/document

Comment: Suggestion: see https://github.com/yjs/yjs-demos and especially the demo https://demos.yjs.dev/atlaskit/atlaskit.html

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Both approaches are similar in that they provide eventual consistency. The difference is in how they do it. One way of looking at it is:

- OT does it by changing **operations**. Operations are sent over the wire and concurrent operations are transformed once they are received.
- CRDTs do it by changing **state**. Operations are made on the local CRDT. Its state is sent over the wire and is merged with the state of a copy. It doesn't matter how many times or in what order merges are made - all copies converge.

You're right, OT is mostly used for text and does predate CRDTs but [research](http://www-sop.inria.fr/orion/COGC/teams/ECOOjournal.pdf) shows that:

> many OT algorithms in the literature do not satisfy convergence properties
>   unlike what was stated by their authors

In other words CRDT merging is commutative while OT transformation functions sometimes are not.

From the [Wikipedia article on CRDT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conflict-free_replicated_data_type):

> OTs are generally complex and non-scalable

There are different kinds of CRDTs (sets, counters, ...) suited for different kinds of problems. There are some that are designed for text editing. For example, Treedoc - [A commutative replicated data type for cooperative editing](https://hal.inria.fr/file/index/docid/445975/filename/icdcs09-treedoc.pdf).

Comment: CRDTs are not only state based, they come in two flavors. State based CvRDTs (convergent replicated data types) and operations based CmRDTs (commutative replicated data types).

Comment: @Magnus
This leads to the question, what is the difference between OT and CmRDT?

Comment: @hrdwdmrbl Well, CmRDTs feature commutative operations, so you don't have to transform them to apply them correctly. Either they fit or you're missing something and have to wait for an operation. OT deals with the problem of conflicting edits with increased time complexity, while CRDT has increased space complexity.

Answer (score 8):

One another notable difference is that:

- OT requires a central server for co-ordination.
- CRDT can adopt any network topology like P2P over WebRTC and it is resilient to network partitions, which makes it decentralized.

Reference: https://youtu.be/B5NULPSiOGw?t=643 by Martin Kleppmann, author of "Designing Data-Intensive Applications".

Comment: I believe this is actually *the* difference between the two, or at least the most notable consequence of the difference. For Operational Transforms, a central server transforms the operations; for a CRDT, you just need to exchange new data with peers, and everyone will know enough information to reconstruct the same final state.

Comment: I was going to share the same video, very useful reference.